# Tensorboard error after installing via pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, tensorboard, undefined-symbol

I have recently attempted to install [tensorboard](https://github.com/dmlc/tensorboard/) via pip as detailed in the README.md. The installation was deemed successful however when I try to run tensorboard after the installation, I keep on receiving an import/undefined symbol error as seen below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.summary import event_file_inspector as efi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/summary/event_file_inspector.py", line 122, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io import copy as Copy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyBytes_AsStringAndSize
```

Have I missed something in the installation process?

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Brad, Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

above error is reported because Tensorboard is installed using pip3(python 3) and TF env is set to python2.7.

use `pip2 install tensorboard`

now tensorboard and tf env both set to python2